# Is this a valid sitemap URL?

Tags: html, sitemap

I have thousands of uique urls that look like this:

```
<url>
  <loc>http://my_site_url/view_profile=1577</loc>
  <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
</url>
```

are these urls that google or any other SE will crawl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, those links will definitely be crawled, but you should ensure that in addition to your sitemap they are in some way properly linked.  Could the urls be improved?  Definitely, in the following ways:

- Seperate words with dashes, not underscores
- Make use of url rewriting to change that = to a /

You may also want to consider using a username rather than profile number.  You might find [Google's Article on URL Structure](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=76329) interesting as well.